# How to represent image instead of data-binding vale? Using angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and little confused with the concepts, can any one take minute and let me know how can i display `green.png` image if `dev.status` is `1` and `red.png` if d`ev.status` is `2`? The following is what i tried but it seems to be the wrong method:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dev of devices">                              
<td>{{dev.slc_id}}</td>
<td>{{dev.location}}</td>

<td>{{dev.status =="1 "? '.assets/img/green.png' : '.assets/img/red.png' }}</td>  
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
<img src='.assets/img/green.png' *ngIf='dev.status == "1"'>
<img src='.assets/img/red.png' *ngIf='dev.status !="1"'>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```html
<tr *ngFor="let dev of devices">
  <td>{{dev.slc_id}}</td>
  <td>{{dev.location}}</td>

  <td *ngIf="dev.status =='1' ">
    <img src=".assets/img/green.png" alt="green">
  </td>

  <td *ngIf="dev.status =='2' ">
    <img src=".assets/img/red.png" alt="red">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngIf` for this condition. 
below is the code you can use for checking the status.

```
<tr *ngFor="let dev of devices">                              
<td>{{dev.slc_id}}</td>
<td>{{dev.location}}</td>

<td>
   <img *ngIf="dev.status == '1'" src=".assets/img/green.png"
   <img *ngIf="dev.status != '1'" src=".assets/img/red.png"
</td>  
</tr>
```